# Creating customized video displaying modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently trying to create a modal box that has a slider with other videos on the left and the main video displayed at the right, basically this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDyNJ.jpg. Also trying to add a scrolling effect to implement more videos, everything will be embedded from youtube. But I am not entirely sure how to do it, got the modal window popping and working, but not sure how to display videos the way I showed up there.

HTML:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header text-center">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <h2>Долна Част</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yIyqdgQILvQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer footer-size">
                <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

CSS:

```
 /* The Modal (background) */
                    .modal {
                        display: none; /* Hidden by default */
                        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
                        z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
                        left: 0;
                        top: 0;
                        width: 100%; /* Full width */
                        height: 100%; /* Full height */
                        overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
                        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
                        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
                    }


                    .modal-content {
                        background-color: #fefefe;
                        margin: 15% auto; 
                        padding: 20px;
                        border: 1px solid #888;
                        width: 80%; 
                    }

                    .close {
                        color: #aaa;
                        float: right;
                        font-size: 28px;
                        font-weight: bold;
                    }

                    .close:hover,
                    .close:focus {
                        color: black;
                        text-decoration: none;
                        cursor: pointer;
                    }




                    .modal {
                        display: none; 
                        position: fixed; 
                        z-index: 1; 
                        padding-top: 100px; 
                        left: 0;
                        top: 0;
                        width: 100%; 
                        height: 100%; 
                        overflow: auto; 
                        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
                        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
                    }


                    .modal-content {
                        position: relative;
                        background-color: #fefefe;
                        margin: auto;
                        padding: 0;
                        border: 1px solid #888;
                        width: 80%;
                        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
                        -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
                       -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
                        animation-name: animatetop;
                        animation-duration: 0.4s
                    }


                    @-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
                        from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
                        to {top:0; opacity:1}
                    }

                    @keyframes animatetop {
                        from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
                        to {top:0; opacity:1}
                    }

                    .close {
                        color: white;
                        float: right;
                        font-size: 28px;
                        font-weight: bold;
                    }

                    .close:hover,
                    .close:focus {
                        color: #000;
                        text-decoration: none;
                        cursor: pointer;
                    }

                    .modal-header {
                        padding: 2px 16px;
                        background-color: #028fcc;
                        color: white;
                    }

                    .modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

                    .modal-footer {
                        padding: 2px 16px;
                        background-color: #028fcc;
                        color: white;
                    }
```

JS:

```
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kufeugbf/1/) with the markup you need to use.
There's too much code to copy-paste, so I won't include any code in the answer.
Basically, you `float` both `menu` and `content` and that's it. I also added some tweaks for modal header and footer, figured you'll need that too.